# sending note that is saved via timeout

Tags: reactjs

I have a textArea, that saves a piece of text, via a timeout.

```
const TIMEOUT_MS = 1000;

getInitialState() {
  return {newNote: this.props.notes};
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // this is necc, because if another user saves the note, it will come via
  // websockets, and we want to show this user that note

  if (this.props.note !=== nextProps.note) {
    this.setState({newNote: nextProps.note});
  }
},

render() {
  ...
  <input 
    value={this.state.newNote}
    onChange={e => {
      const v = e.target.value;
      this.setState({newNote: v});
      window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.timeout = window.setTimeout(
        _ => api.save(this.state.newNote),
        TIMEOUT_MS
      );
    }} />
}
```

Consider this case though

- User types "abc"
- waits 1 second (api request sends to save "abc")
- User types "def"
- API request comes back, causing componentWillReceiveProps to replace newNote with "abc"

Is there an elegant solution to handle this problem?

Right now, I am considering having an `updated-at` key on the server, and comparing it with the clients `updated-at`

Comment: you can consider updating your local app state optimistically and ignore the server response when the result is successful

Comment: You can also pass a user id along with the API request, and if the update is from the current user, do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for posterity, I reasonable solution would have been to keep an `updated-at` key. The client would optimistically update, and only accept a server update if it was newer.